# Service doesn't start after device reboot

Tags: android

I want to start my service after reboot device if the service was working before reboot. I handled boot completed intent but my application is terminated when i want to start service again.

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BootCompletedIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            context.getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            context.getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
        }
   }
}
```

Part of LocationService:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    ...

    startForeground(NotificationCreator.getNotificationId(), NotificationCreator.getNotification(this));
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    ...

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
    }
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
    {
        Toasty.warning(this, "Turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isPause = true;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, this);

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Part of class where i start service:

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getContext(), LocationService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(IntentExtras.COURSE, Parcels.wrap(course));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        getActivity().startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location1.gps" />

<application>

    <service android:name=".services.LocationService" />

    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

I start application and start service, when service is working I restart device. After reboot onReceive method is called in BroadcastReceiver. I can handle break point in first line in this method but the code is stop being executing after call start service. I tried to stop service before start them in this method but id dost'n change anything. I also tried to start service after launch application after reboot without broadcast receiver but it also doesn't help.

Comment: How do you normally start it, and is `onReceive()` ever called?

Comment: Is the `onReceive` method in your being called? Do you define it in your manifest? Note that in my experience I found that some devices have the `on boot completed` intent blocked.

Comment: @matekome please add manifest details

Comment: I edited my question. BroadcastReceiver works I can debug onReceive method but code stop being executing when i want to start service.

Comment: Remove the break-point, this code should work.

Comment: put your BootCompletedIntentReceiver codes into `try {} catch` and get it's exeption message and post here

Comment: Have you solved your problem ?

I have a closed problem : I flash my device, at first start my apps start automatically but ONLY at first start, then the apps does'nt start ...

Answer (score 0):

add this on your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="BootCompletedIntentReceiver">  
        <intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  
        </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Comment: There is everything ok with BroadcastReceiver. OnReceive method is being called but program stop executing when I want to start service.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I have an idea why

You can't run this code inside a `Service`. It has to be run in an `Activity`.

```
if (
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) 
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && 
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
){
    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        Toasty.warning(this, "Turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isPause = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Service works. When i start service everything is ok. It dasn't work when i want to start service again after restart device.

Comment: @matekome Remove the code I've included in my answer, and try it again. Add a logging line in the `onStart` method to check whether the service has started or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the permission in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Also, in yourAndroidManifest.xml, define your service and listen for the BOOT_COMPLETED action:

```
<service android:name=".MyService" android:label="My Service">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.myapp.MyService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
   android:name=".receiver.StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver"
   android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you need to define the receiver that will get the BOOT_COMPLETED action and start your service.

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
  }
}
```

And now your service should be running when the phone starts up.